# What would be the simplest physical implementation of a CNOT operation between spin and energy DoF's?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization, openpulse

I'm working on a project where I'm considering a two-level system ("atom" for convenience) which possesses two linearly independent degrees of freedom, one of them a spin degree of freedom with in Hilbert space $\{|\uparrow\rangle,~|\downarrow\rangle\}$ and the other an energy degree of freedom in Hilbert space $\{|g\rangle,~|e\rangle\}$. One of the operations I'd like to be able to implement is a CNOT gate between these degrees of freedom with the energy DoF as control qubit and the spin DoF as target qubit. I'm having a bit of a hard time determining a viable physical scheme that could implement such a gate on the "pulse level", although I'm convinced that there is one.

It seems to me that the application of a magnetic field to the atom where we prepare the system such that $\mathbf{\mu}\cdot\mathbf{B}=|E_e-E_g|$ followed by a $\pi$-rotation pulse in the spin basis might be on the right track but I'm genuinely very lost beyond that ill-formed idea.

Has any work been done on this topic and would anyone have any ideas that might help?

EDIT: If it matters, the specific CNOT gate I want is $(|\uparrow\rangle\langle{\downarrow}|+|\downarrow\rangle\langle{\uparrow}|)\otimes|g\rangle\langle{g}|+\hat{\mathbb{I}}\otimes|e\rangle\langle{e}|$

Comment: Crossposted to physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766045/how-to-achieve-physical-implementation-of-a-cnot-gate-between-spin-and-energy-de